# Is there a principle for choosing between embedding a struct itself or the pointer to a struct inside a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This is a code snippet from qemu.(qemu-5.1.0 include/hw/arm/smmu-common.h)

```
typedef struct SMMUDevice {
    void               *smmu;
    PCIBus             *bus;
    int                devfn;
    IOMMUMemoryRegion  iommu;
    AddressSpace       as;
    uint32_t           cfg_cache_hits;
    uint32_t           cfg_cache_misses;
    QLIST_ENTRY(SMMUDevice) next;
} SMMUDevice;
```

I've seen many such codes until now but I am now curious if there is any principle/rule in choosing between

1. embedding a struct A inside a struct B
2. embedding a pointer to the struct A inside a struct B

Two things that come to my mind right away is that if a struct A is to be shared by many structs, it is better to use pointer. or if the struct containing the struct(that is, struct B) is to be frequently passed as a function argument, it would be better to use pointer(pointer to struct B as argument, or pointer to A inside struct B and struct B is the argument) because copying the struct to stack would take long time.

I am curious if there are other important rules.

Comment: It depends on domain and langauge. For C, some pointers point to hardware instead of just data.

Comment: Other possibilities: The lifetime of the two structs are different, the inner struct is created/managed by some other module, the inner struct is optional, ..

Comment: Pretty much a case-by-case call. You've twigged to the sharing case, but what if the outer structure is the owner of the inner structure and everyone else sharing have pointers to it? How and how often you pass something shouldn't be an issue. No matter how something is allocated or embedded, you can always get its address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no correct answer because it depends on what you want to use them for. Storing a struct inside another struct is generally more efficient, since it gives faster access and better data cache use.

However, it isn't as flexible. If you wish to swap out the whole contents of a big struct for something else, it goes much faster to just swap two pointers than doing a hard copy of all the data. Pointers also enable different forms of allocation - you could have a static storage struct with a pointer at dynamically allocated memory for example.

---

> if a struct A is to be shared by many structs, it is better to use pointer

I don't see how that matters at all. It's just a `.` vs `->` notation by the code using it.

> or if the struct containing the struct(that is, struct B) is to be frequently passed as a function argument, it would be better to use pointer

No that's nonsense, you'd always pass the outer struct through a pointer no matter what members it got. Passing it by value doesn't make any sense in either scenario.

Comment: `I don't see how that matters at all. It's just a . vs -> notation by the code using it.` OP means that if `struct A` contains a pointer to `struct Member`, and `struct B` contains a pointer to the **same** `struct Member` - then a pointer must be used for the `struct Member` and not a direct member. Not a matter of notation.

Comment: Indeed I believe this is the case in QEMU, which inspired OP's question - the `PCIBus*` member (which is a pointer) points to the same `PCIBus` shared by many emulated devices.

Comment: it's late but thanks for the answer and comments.